# syntax error when using while to loop infinitely in a simple shell script

Tags: shell, while-loop

a simple shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
str="hello"
while [ -n $str ]; do
  #do noting, just loop infinitely
done
```

this script throws an error, like this:

```
./while.sh: 5: ./while.sh: Syntax error: "done" unexpected
```

why, and what is the correct way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `do` something! The shortest thing you can do is this:

```
#!/bin/sh
str="hello"
while [ -n "$str" ]; do
  :
done
```

`:`, a shorthand for `true`, does nothing and returns success.

By the way, I quoted your string `$str`, as this is something that you should always do.